# How to show the labels of the column in a groupby operation

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe with columns:  `Sentiment` and `Role`

```
Sentiment       Role
positive        manager
positive        worker
negative        leader
positive        director
negative        leader
positive        manager
negative        manager
```

I want to groupy this dataframe by sentiment and count how many time a `role` has each sentiment label, like the output below:

**Desired output**

```
             worker    leader    director    manager
positive       1         0           1         2
negative       0         2           0         1
```

I am trying:

```
df.groupby('Sentiment').agg({'Role':'count'})
```

But the result is missing the label of each role.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# use cross tab and provide row and indexes
df2=pd.crosstab(index=df['Sentiment'], columns=df['Role'] ).reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)

# defie column index sequence
idx=['Sentiment', 'worker', 'leader', 'director','manager']

# reindex the columns, and sort the rows
df2=df2.reindex(idx, axis=1 ).sort_values('Sentiment', ascending=False)
df2
```

```
    Sentiment   worker  leader  director    manager
1   positive         1      0         1     2
0   negative         0      2         0     1
```